# lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to evaluate the sem model from a dataset, some of the data are in likert scale i.e from 1-5. and some of the data are **COUNTS** generated from the computer log for some of the activity.

Whereas while performing the fits the laveen is giving me the error as:

> lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate

To mitigate this warning I want to `scale` some of the variables. But couldn't understand the way for doing that.

```
Log_And_SurveyResult <- read_excel("C:/Users/Aakash/Desktop/analysis/Log-And-SurveyResult.xlsx")

model <- '
  Reward =~ REW1 + REW2 + REW3 + REW4
  ECA =~  ECA1 + ECA2 + ECA3
  Feedback =~ FED1 + FED2 + FED3 + FED4
  Motivation =~ Reward + ECA + Feedback
  Satisfaction =~ a*MaxTimeSpentInAWeek + a*TotalTimeSpent + a*TotalLearningActivityView 
  
  Motivation ~ Satisfaction'

fit <- sem(model,data = Log_And_SurveyResult)

summary(fit, standardized=T, std.lv = T)

fitMeasures(fit, c("cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"))
```

I want to scale some of the variables like `MaxTimeSpentInAWeek` and `TotalTimeSpent`

Could you please help me figure out how to scale the variables? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `scale(MaxTimeSpentInAWeek)`. This will scale your variable to mean = 0 and variance = 1. E.g:

```
    Log_And_SurveyResult$MaxTimeSpentInAWeek <- 
    scale(Log_And_SurveyResult$MaxTimeSpentInAWeek)
    Log_And_SurveyResult$TotalTimeSpent <- 
    scale(Log_And_SurveyResult$TotalTimeSpent)
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: how to use that scaled_MaxTime in the `model`?

Comment: Why dont you transforme the data before including them in the model?

Comment: can you help on how to scale before and use that in the model?

Comment: i have loaded the data in `Log_And_SurveyResult` variable

Comment: still the same warning...i don't know why I am getting the warning `some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate`. isn't this the way of doing that to scale?

Comment: Try to scale all the variables. Maybe the problem lies not with the two mentioned variables but with others

Comment: yeah, the warning has gone now, maybe some other variables were also causing the issues...one other question, I have scale the variables that predict the construct `Satisfaction`, but I haven't scale the variables that loads the `Motivation`. So, if we scale some variables do we need to other variables too?

Comment: I can not say for sure. But I would say it is not a problem. Furthermore, you standardize your results anyway. `summary(fit, standardized=T, std.lv = T)`. With the input `standardized=T`. So I would say it is not a problem. But as said I am not 100% sure. But I am glab I could help.

Comment: with `std.lv = T` it is showing error as `Error in .local(object, ...) : unused argument (std.lv = TRUE)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221926/discussion-between-akshaykriti-and-elias).

Answer (score 2):

As [Elias pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023310/4112892), the difference in the magnitude between the variables is huge and it is suggested to scale the variables.
The warning gives a hint and inspecting `varTable(fit)` returns summary information about the variables in a fitted `lavaan` object.

Rather than running `scale()` separately on each column, you could use `apply()` on a subset or on your whole `data.frame`:

```r
## Scale the variables in the 4th and 7h column
Log_And_SurveyResult[, c(4, 7)] <- apply(Log_And_SurveyResult[, c(4, 7)],  2, scale)

## Scale the whole data.frame
Log_And_SurveyResult <- apply(Log_And_SurveyResult,  2, scale)
```